# Extract filename from path in field calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, regular-expression

I try to extract the filename from a path in my attribute table in QGIS.

**regex_substr** should be the way to go I assume, but testing all kinds of example from the web did not work out.

I have images which I want to link, but the original pathes are not valid anymore, cause all images from different people went into one single folder now.

Example paths:

```
./20170608-attachments/p__20170608_122128.jpg
./20170603-attachments/p__20170603_095124.jpg
```

here I would just like to populate a new field with `p__20170608_122128.jpg` etc. only.

A solution, that would give me the rest of the string after the last `/` would be the most versatile one in my case, I assume.

Any ideas?

Comment: YouTube may try your_string[your_string.rfind('/')+1:] ír

Comment: Try rfind('/') instead öv regexp function

Comment: There is no such thing as rfind in the field calculator expressions for strings, otherwise I would have used it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a working solution for **Linux** myself shortly after posting the question.

```
([^/]+$)
```

gives the rest of the string (in my case the filename) after the last `/`

```
regexp_substr("column_with_full_path", '([^/]+$)')
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8945477

For **Windows**, referring to [cm1's comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259287/extract-filename-from-path-in-field-calculator/259290?noredirect=1#comment441666_259290) below:

```
regexp_substr("column_with_full_path", '([^\\\\]+$)')
```

Comment: In my case, I had backslashes (Windows) in the field named 'location'. This worked nicely: regexp_substr("location", '([^\\\\\]+$)'). Use double backslashes to represent a single backslash (one 'escapes' the other).